# Why am I getting "Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction" in this code?

Tags: ios, swift, social-media

I'm trying to build a social network app for ios for a school project. My `@IBAction` function for signing in doesn't work and I don't know why. The error I'm getting is: "Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction"

Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!`

    var userUid: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        if let _ = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid") {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "Messages", sender: nil)
        }

        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            if segue.identifier == "SignUp" {

                if let destination = segue.destination as? SignUpVC {
                    if self.userUid != nil{
                        destination.userUid = userUid
                    }
                    if self.emailField.text != nil {
                        destination.emailField = emailField.text
                    }
                    if self.passwordField.text != nil {
                        destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @IBAction func SignIn (_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text{
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:{
                (user, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    self.userUid = user?.user.uid
                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.userUid, forKey: "uid")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Messages", sender: nil)
                } else {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUp", sender: nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why is your `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method inside viewWillAppear? thats either a bad copy/paste into here or you need to move that out. It also looks as if your IBAction could be inside another method too, either that or you've declared one static somewhere. please tidy up this code, it's quite difficult to read and is obviously causing issues.

Comment: Your mistake is in scopes. Functions can not contain other fuctions in swift.

Comment: Functions can contain functions however putting prepare: inside viewDidLoad: is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for it is that your `SignIn` is not an instance method, it's a nested function inside `viewDidAppear`. Add another closing parenthesis in `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    if let _ = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid") {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Messages", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

and remove one at the end of file

Answer (score 0):

function `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` should be in class scope not nested inside `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if let _ = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid"){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Messages", sender: nil)
    } 
}

@IBAction func SignIn (_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text{
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:{
            (user, error) in
            if error == nil{
                self.userUid = user?.user.uid
                KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.userUid, forKey: "uid")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Messages", sender: nil)
            } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUp", sender: nil)
            }
        })
    }
} 
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){ 
    if segue.identifier == "SignUp"{ 
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SignUpVC { 
            if self.userUid != nil {
                destination.userUid = userUid
            }  
            destination.emailField = emailField.text 
            destination.passwordField = passwordField.text 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You prepare for segue, and sign in function were both nested inside the `viewDidAppear` method. Using comments can help break up the functions visually.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!`
    // MARK: Properties
    var userUid: String!
    // MARK: Lifecycle
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let _ = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid") {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "Messages", sender: nil)
        }
    }
    // MARK: Navigation
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "SignUp" {

            if let destination = segue.destination as? SignUpVC {
                if self.userUid != nil{
                    destination.userUid = userUid
                }
                if self.emailField.text != nil {
                    destination.emailField = emailField.text
                }
                if self.passwordField.text != nil {
                    destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func SignIn (_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text{
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:{
                (user, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    self.userUid = user?.user.uid
                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.userUid, forKey: "uid")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Messages", sender: nil)
                } else {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUp", sender: nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            if segue.identifier == "SignUp" {

                if let destination = segue.destination as? SignUpVC {
                    if self.userUid != nil{
                        destination.userUid = userUid
                    }
                    if self.emailField.text != nil {
                        destination.emailField = emailField.text
                    }
                    if self.passwordField.text != nil {
                        destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @IBAction func SignIn (_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text{
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:{
                (user, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    self.userUid = user?.user.uid
                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.userUid, forKey: "uid")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Messages", sender: nil)
                } else {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUp", sender: nil)
                }
            })
        }
```

should be outside `viewDidAppear`